# perform a function when form values change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to call a function when the value of any form value changes.

This is my code:

```
function reload()
{
  tmp = findSWF("chart");

  x = tmp.reload("chart.php", false);
}

function findSWF(movieName) {
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!= -1) {
    return window["ie_" + movieName];
  } else {
    return document[movieName];
  }
}

$(".formclass").change(function() {
    reload();
});
```

If i make a link with an `onclick` action, it works, but using the last `.change` action, nothing happens.
Ideally, i could also pass the name and value of what has changed to that url

Comment: Try setting it as an attribute "onchange"  I can't quite remember but I had this issue and I think thats how I worked around it.

Answer (score 5):

the change event only kicks in when you changed the value AND the control loses focus for text controls:

> The change event is sent to an element
>   when its value changes. This event is
>   limited to  elements,
>    boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes,
>   checkboxes, and radio buttons, the
>   event is fired immediately when the
>   user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the
>   event is deferred until the element
>   loses focus.

if you want to trigger the function as the user types in the control, try keydown() or keypress()